# Rotating button animation doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a button, when it's tapped, it should rotate itself, here's my code:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI)
    rotateAnimation.speed = 3.0
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 6000
    calculateButton.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: self.calculator!.iterateWPItems())
        self.calculateButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

However, sometimes when I tap the button, it immediately goes back to normal state then rotates, sometimes the button changes to dark selected state, and doesn't animate at all, tasks after the animates will get finished. If I don't stop the animation, it starts after `openCircle` is finished.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Why do you remove animations from `calculateButton` after you add it?

Comment: @alexburtnik after `openCircle` finishes, the animation should stop

Comment: But it will happen immediately unless `openCircle` is blocking main thread.

Comment: Please add `openCircle` implementation

Comment: `openCircle` is quite complicated, but it should take 40 seconds to finish

Comment: @alexburtnik and it's ok to block the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for answering, I found the solution myself after a crash course on multithreading, the problem is I blocked the main thread with `openCircle` method.

Here's the updated code:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI)
    rotateAnimation.speed = 3.0
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        self.openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: self.calculator!.iterateWPItems()){}
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.calculateButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
    }
    self.calculateButton.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: with this method, your button can be clicked multiple times, and that would cause the rotation to speed up each time. I'm glad you found a solution for your problem though :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not setting `duration` of your animation. 
   Replace this

```
rotateAnimation.speed = 3.0
```

with this

```
rotateAnimation.duration = 3.0
```

2. > @alexburtnik and it's ok to block the main thread

No, it's **not ok**. You should add a `completion` parameter in `openCircle` method and call it whenever it's animation (or whatever) is finished. If you block main thread, you will have a frozen UI, which is strongly discouraged.

3. If you're unsure that `calculateButtonTapped` is called on main thread, you should dispatch first part of your method as well. Everything related to UI **must** be done on the main thread.

It should look similar to this:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI)
    rotateAnimation.duration = 3.0
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity //endless animation
    calculateButton.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

    self.openCircle(
        withCenter: sender.center,
        dataSource: self.calculator!.iterateWPItems(),
        completion: {
            self.calculateButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    })
}

func openCircle(withCenter: CGPoint, dataSource: DataSourceProtocol, completion: (()->Void)?) {
    //do your staff and call completion when you're finished
    //don't block main thread!
}
```

Comment: Isn't `repeatCount` equivalent to duration?

Comment: No, it is not. `repeatCount` will repeat your rotation 6000 times, but it will still be immediate, since you haven't set `duration`, which is 0 by default

Comment: Actually when it's not set it still works sometimes, and now I set the duration  it still doesn't work

Comment: That's because you probably block your main thread. I can't tell for sure because I don't know what you're doing in `openCircle` method for 40 seconds

Comment: Is it rotating if you comment `Dispatch.main.async` block altogether?

Comment: yes it is, but after `openCircle` finishes, I commented out the `removeAnimation` line

Comment: Check the updated answer, I've added an example. You don't need to dispatch anything unless you call `calculateButtonTapped` manually from another thread.

Comment: nope, now the animation starts after openCircle is finished and doesn't stop

Comment: there's animation going on in openCircle, does that affect the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127164/discussion-between-alexburtnik-and-bright-future).

Comment: I found the answer, `duration` really doesn't matter

Comment: And what matters?

Comment: it's the problem of multithreading, you could see my own answer. Thanks for your help any way

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in order to rotate a button that is clicked by connecting the button to the action on a storyboard. You can of course call this function by passing any UIButton as the sender!

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard (sender.layer.animation(forKey: "rotate") == nil) else { return }

    let rotationDuration: Float = 3.0

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animation.toValue = Float.pi * rotationDuration
    animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(rotationDuration)
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity

    sender.layer.add(animation, forKey: "rotate")

}
```

Change the `rotationDuration` to whatever time length you want for a full rotation. You could also adjust the function further to take that as an argument.

**Edit**: Added a guard statement so that the rotations don't keep adding up every time that the button is tapped.

Comment: Could I get a comment in regards to the downvote please? Thanks

Comment: I down voted it because it's in fact the same as my own code

Comment: @BrightFuture I agree it is very similar - The main thing I changed is the inclusion of a `guard` statement so that the animation wouldn't try to start again which could be causing it to revert to its normal state. I also set the `duration` rather than `speed` but that doesn't really matter if you know how fast you want it to go, rather than by the duration for a complete revolution.

Comment: @BrightFuture OK sure, it is very similar. Can I go through the steps with you as I may have misunderstood the question? 1) you want to press the button to rotate it 6000 times at a speed of 3.0 (not a duration). 2) When clicking on the button, you don't want it to to reset the animation. 3) You want to perform your `openCircle` function after the animation has finished.

Comment: I found the solution myself, you can have a look.

Comment: I'll up vote your answer, but maybe you should delete it after, as it doesn't help :)